php mysqli_stmt_execute() returns false with no error reported under mysql v8.0.36-28
My web hoster (Siteground) just migrated MySql from v5.7 to v8.0.
Now some parts of my code no longer work.
The version of PHP (v7.4) has not changed.
The offending item involves a call to mysqli_stmt_execute() which now throws an exception.
Here is my original code (which worked fine under MySql v5.7):-
if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
  error_log("mysql error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
  error_log("prep_bind_exec_2(): mysqli_stmt_execute returned false");
  return false;
} 


In MySql v8.0 this same code now throws an exception:-
Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute in 
Stack trace:
mysqli_stmt_execute(Object(mysqli_stmt))
prep_bind_exec_2(Object(mysqli), '  SELECT DISTIN...', 'ssssssdd', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', 0, 1000000000)


From the PHP documentation page, I see that in the procedural style, the syntax for mysqld_stmt_execute() is as follows:-
mysqli_stmt_execute(mysqli_stmt $statement, ?array $params = null): bool
The second optional $params argument is only needed from PHP v8.1 onwards, apparently.
Nevertheless, I changed my code as follows to see if it might make a difference:-
if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt, ['2','1','2','3','4','4','0','1000000000']))
{
  error_log("mysql error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
  error_log("prep_bind_exec_2(): mysqli_stmt_execute returned false");
  return false;
}


Result: mysqli_stmt_execute() now returns false but mysqli_error() returns an empty string.
So, now I am a bit stumped as I don't know whether mysqli_stmt_execute() needs an $params array or not.
The SQL is as follows:-
SELECT DISTINCT CONTACT.contact_id, CONTACT.address_region, CONTACT.cost_to_request
FROM CONTACT 
LEFT JOIN STAKEHOLDER       ON CONTACT.contact_id = STAKEHOLDER.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_RANGE     ON CONTACT.contact_id = PRODUCT_RANGE.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN CAPABILITY        ON CONTACT.contact_id = CAPABILITY.contact_id  
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_FEATURE   ON CONTACT.contact_id = PRODUCT_FEATURE.contact_id 
WHERE 
CONTACT.active = '1'
AND STAKEHOLDER.role_id IN (?)  
AND CAPABILITY.technology_id IN (?,?,?,?) 
AND PRODUCT_RANGE.product_type_id IN (?)
LIMIT ?,?


with the bound parameters (placeholders) as follows:-
params=["2","1","2","3","4","4",0,1000000000]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76246288/can-i-force-mysqli-functions-to-return-error-codes-instead-of-throwing-exception

@ADyson: Sorry, neither of these links are relevant to my query.

But they are relevant to the ancient, obsolete way you're handling errors. Hence why they are just comments, not answers

['2','1','2','3','4','4','0','1000000000'] from your code and ["2","1","2","3","4","4",0,1000000000] from the bound parameters below looks different - did you check why this looks different?

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause helps (as in: your parameters for LIMIT should use integers, not strings)

What @NicoHaase said, plus this - if your ids (role_id, technology_id, etc) are setup as INT(11) (or any other type of integer) in your tables, try binding them (and providing them) as integers as well.

Thanks to everyone who provided comments and questions.
I managed to resolve this issue by changing the bound parameters from a mixture of ints and strings to just strings.
In the end the exception thrown in response to my call to mysqli_stmt_execute() was a red herring. I assume this change is a direct result of the move from MySql v5.7 to v8.0, although I have no idea why..
My working solution: Instead of passing in multiple arrays, I am now using array_merge() to collate one single array, with all elements as strings, rather than a mix of types.
// variable pattern matching based on total count of array items + attribute values + LIMIT values
$pattern  = str_repeat('s', count($chosenRoles) + count($chosenTechnologies) + count($chosenProductTypes));
$pattern .= "sssssssss";
$pattern .= "ss";       // LIMIT min, max

// stack all parameters into one array
$stack = array_merge($chosenRoles, $chosenTechnologies, $chosenProductTypes, 
$arr_att_1_id, $arr_att_1_min, $arr_att_1_max, 
$arr_att_2_id, $arr_att_2_min, $arr_att_2_max, 
$arr_att_3_id, $arr_att_3_min, $arr_att_3_max,
$arr_limit_min, $arr_limit_max
);

/* $stmt = prep_bind_exec_2($mysqli, $query, $pattern,
...$chosenRoles, ...$chosenTechnologies, ...$chosenProductTypes , 
...$arr_att_1_id, ...$arr_att_1_min, ...$arr_att_1_max          ,
...$arr_att_2_id, ...$arr_att_2_min, ...$arr_att_2_max          ,
...$arr_att_3_id, ...$arr_att_3_min, ...$arr_att_3_max          ,
...$arr_limit_min, ...$arr_limit_max
);*/

$stmt = prep_bind_exec_2($mysqli, $query, $pattern, ...$stack);

and
function prep_bind_exec_2(mysqli $mysqli, string $query, string $pattern, ...$params)
{
   try
   {    
      //////////////////////////////
      // check incoming
      //////////////////////////////
      if ($mysqli==null || empty($query))
      {
          error_log ("mysqli==null or empty(query)");
          return false;
      }
        
      //////////////////////////////
      // prepare query
      //////////////////////////////
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
      if ($stmt == false)
      {
          error_log ("prep_bind_exec_2(): mysqli_prepare returned false");
          return false;
      }
        
      //////////////////////////////
      // bind params
      //////////////////////////////
      if (mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $pattern, ...$params) == false)
      {
          error_log ("prep_bind_exec_2(): mysqli_stmt_bind_param returned false");
          return false;
      }

      //////////////////////////////
      // execute statement
      //////////////////////////////
      if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) == false)
      {
          error_log("prep_bind_exec_2(): mysqli_stmt_execute returned false");
          error_log("mysql error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
          return false;
      }

      return $stmt;
   }
   catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) 
   {
     report ($e->__toString());
   }

   return false;
}

The above has resolved the issue.
However, I will keep investigating whether this is the best solution, or just one solution that happens to work right now.
I hope this helps others who may be suffering the same demise in their previously working code due to migrations in MySql, although I am stil not sure whether MySql is to blame here.
